# Log4net Raygun Tags

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender, raygun

Is there any way to set the raygun tags in config level
I have tried in code level for exception

```
new RaygunClient().SendInBackground(exception, new List<string> { "Error", "Mq-Translator" });
```

But I would need to set the tag in project level for the service

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the RaygunAppender from [log4net raygun on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net.Raygun/), the tags are set from:

```
 .SetTags(ExtractTags(loggingEvent.GetProperties()))
```

This will extract all the properties set in the logging context.

If you set the properties as explained on the [set properties on context manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html) they will show up in the tags.